# AngularJs filter to return matching regex value

Tags: regex, angularjs

I want to create an angular filter to grab solely the URL from a value eg:

p.comments.data returns this:

```
"check this http://www.newlook.com/shop/womens/dresses/navy-short-sleeve-check-tunic-dress-_320165649"

 <li ng-repeat="p in pics">                          
    <p>{{p.comments.data}}</p>
</li>
```

Not sure how to go about this. Thanks

Comment: And what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex: `(\bhttps?\:\/\/(www)?\.\w+\.\w+(\/[\w\d\-]+)*)`. Your match will be the first group.

Probably can be made way shorter, but still, this should do the job. Also at third group you get the last part of the link.

Demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/dR7pL5/1).

Comment: thanks probably should work, but how can I write the filter? maybe replace all everything apart from the regex match ie URL